# Tweets to Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I am trying to find a way to convert tweets from RSS feed to lotus notes documents. Does anyone know how to do it?

Best, 
Frederic

Comment: That's a very high level question: have you looked at working with RSS feeds programmatically? Do you know how to create documents programmatically? In other words: what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an RSS reader in LotusScript years ago.  I had planned to open source it on OpenNTF, but never got around to actually cleaning it for posting.  I can offer it "as-is" [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3991319/v3template.zip). I did write several [blog](http://www.poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/poweroftheschwartz.nsf/d6plinks/RSCZ-69GRRD) [posts](http://www.poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/poweroftheschwartz.nsf/d6plinks/RSCZ-6CYLGD) about some of the key functions.  Lance Spellman wrote an RSS reader for Notes that uses Java agents instead of LotusScript, and he did [post his code](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/66d9103768cc2fed85256c59006b5433/2dd20dd6c1e05af986256e4a0072e356!OpenDocument) to OpenNTF.  Thomas Adrian has also [posted](http://www.notessidan.se/blogg.nsf/plink/TADN-7MXCJB) code that imports Twitter feeds into Notes, though I don't know if he's using RSS feeds or Twitter APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough cred to comment so hence an answer of sorts. I certainly rate Richard's response however if you are intending to consume twitter via RSS, you need to check if you can post March 2013 as most RSS support is being removed by Twitter.

Basically, to extract anything out of Twitter will require you to authorise via oAuth first and this includes search. This will affect Richard's response however the solution is sound until then.